# Drivers to Keyframes

Tags: unity, shape-keys, .fbx

if got an issue. I'm trying to controll shapekeys with bones. So far so good. It works. But when I am trying to export the animation as fbx it just disappears. So I thought of baking the action on the mesh. So the Shapekeys are keyframed. I can#T find a solution to this. if i mannually keyframe the shapekeys, everything looks fine in Unity, but with the drivers it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any solution to this problem. I am really stuck and I need your help.
Thank you!

Comment: If you disable the "All Action" & "NLA Strips" options in the FBX exporter window, the shape keys will be baked (you have to add keyframes to the mesh object too, not only to the armature). In this way only the active action will be exported, so you have to export as many fbx as many animations you have.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Yeah I realized it too. That's a bit annoying, that I have to export the mesh with the rif together. Thank you for the help!